# Insert images to a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I ask this question a week ago, but no one help me to solve the problem, here is my question, I hope that this time someone help me...

I'm trying to insert jQuery code that contains images to a `<td>` in a table but the images are out of the table bounds. I tried many ways but it didn't work.

**Javscript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
       var $elements = $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour');

       function anim_loop(index) {
           $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(4000, function() {
               var $self = $(this);
               setTimeout(function() {
               $self.fadeOut(4000);
               anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
               }, 6000);
           });
        }
        anim_loop(0); // start with the first element

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1     /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>title</title>

 <style>
 div {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
 table-layout:fixed;

 }

 </style>


 </head>

 <body>


 <table align="center" width="975" border="1" >

 <tr height="54">
 <td width="250" width="185">
 <img src="logo.png" />
 </td>
 <td width="303" colspan="3">
 bolbol
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>  
 <td height="480" colspan="3">
 <div id="imageHolder">
 <div id="picOne"><img src="pic1.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
 <div id="picTwo"><img src="pic1b.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
 <div id="picTree"><img src="2b.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
 <div id="picFour"><img src="2.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td width="206">

 </td>
 <td width="444">

 </td>
 <td>

 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Here are the images:

http://postimage.org/image/i5g1jceuv/

http://postimage.org/image/n5hfzp28b/

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can have a table like structure using just div's. Which will really help you to understand the flow (IMO).

Comment: You dont have jquery referenced in this page anywhere, it will not work without it... which version are you using and how are you referencing it? This is how to include it from the jquery site: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>` also this has to be before the jquery code in your page

Comment: of course i have,here is the reference(i just forgot to write it in the example): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: I was trying to say you should add your **complete** original code, not the broken code after you tried to mix my answer in with it. The reason it did not work is because all divs were hidden. also version 1.4 of jquery is very old and it could be a compatibility issue. if you are learning jquery you should use the latest version, support will be much better. If you have to use that version then if the below code does not work with 1.4 you should ask a new question about that.

Comment: i am now using version 1.9.0 of jquery, and its still not working. you said that its not working because all the divs are hidden, i dont know how to fix it! please help me.

Comment: Did you try the new code at the bottom of my answer?

Comment: yes i did, and it still didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `table-layout: fixed` to the table, that'll prevent the images from "going out of the table bounds"

Answer (score 1):

Tested your code, The table was adjusting to fit each of my images, maybe you have other code on your page which is forcing the size?

I dont know the dimensions of your images but if you add:

```
<div id="picTwo"><img src="2.jpg" width="50px" /></div>
```

A width to the image they will all be the same size.
If they are over 975px wide you should consider resizing them for the web...

I also got all the images displaying then one disappearing at a time but I assume you are restricting the height of the table cell somewhere else (I tested with jquery 1.9.0)
As @Mr_Green said, a table is a weird structure for this, Try:

The html:

```
<div id="imageHolder">
<div id="picOne"><img src="1.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
<div id="picTwo"><img src="2.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
<div id="picTree"><img src="3.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
<div id="picFour"><img src="4.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
</div>
```

With css:

```
#imageHolder{
width:975px;
background-color:#564;
padding:10px;
}
```

(change the bg colour and padding after you test it).

In the javascript add this line to hide the elements by default (After the var $elements... line):

```
$('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour').hide();
```

Edit:
I rearranged the code so the next picture wont display until the last one is gone, also the function does not need to be in the document ready:

```
var $elements = $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour');
function anim_loop(index) {
    $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(4000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(4000, function(){
                anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
            });

        }, 6000);
    });
} 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour').hide();
    anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
});
```

New edit:
This has the complete working version of the code with no table, all images loaded dynamically via wiki commons. latest jquery via jquery.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1     /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<table align="center" width="975" border="1" >

<tr height="54">
<td width="250" width="185">
<img src="logo.png" />
</td>
<td width="303" colspan="3">
bolbol
</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td height="480" colspan="3">
 <div id="imageHolder">
 <div id="picOne"><img     src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Basel_2012-10-02_Mattes_%2812%29.JPG/800px-Basel_2012-10-02_Mattes_%2812%29.JPG" width="975px" /></div>
 <div id="picTwo"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Natanjap052.jpg/800px-Natanjap052.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
 <div id="picTree"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Chelone_lyonii2.jpg/800px-Chelone_lyonii2.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
<div id="picFour"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Long-tailed_Duck_%28Clangula_hyemalis%29_%286663015595%29.jpg" width="975px" /></div>
 </div>
</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
<td width="206">

 </td>
<td width="444">

</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
</table>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $elements = $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour');
function anim_loop(index) {
    $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(4000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(4000, function(){
                anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
            });

        }, 6000);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour').hide();
    anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do u have an email that i can send you the whole code with the pics?

Comment: This new code is self contained and works with no external files, copy it to a file and run it.

Comment: i copied the code, it didn't work.... do u have an email that i can send u the whole files?

Comment: If you take the bottom section of code (which I now added your table code too), save it to a file and open it in a browser It will work. if you have some other files that need to be added then it is a different question